# ElasticSearch: Accidentally starting 2 instances in same server

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

So I accidentally started 2 ElasticSearch instances on the same machine. One with port 9200, the other with port 9201. This means there's 2 cluster nodes, each with the same name, and each has 1/2 of the total shards for each index.

If I kill one of the instances, I now end up with 1 instance having 1/2 the shards.

How do I fix this problem? I want to have just 1 instance with all the shards in it (like it used to be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO... there is a clean way to resolve this. Although I must say the ElasticSearch documentation is very very confusing (all these buzzwords like cluster and zen discovery boggles my mind!)

1) 
Now, if you have 2 instances, one in port 9200, and the other in 9201. And you want ALL the shards to be in 9200.

Run this command to disable allocation in the 9201 instance. You can change persistent to transient if you want this change to not be permanent. I'd keep it persistent so this doesn't ever happen again.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9201/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.disable_allocation" : true
    }
}'
```

2) Now, run the command to MOVE all the shards in the 9201 instance to 9200.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
    "commands" : [ {
          "move" : 
            {
              "index" : "<NAME OF INDEX HERE>", "shard" : <SHARD NUMBER HERE>, 
              "from_node" : "<ID OF 9201 node>", "to_node" : "<ID of 9200 node>"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

You need to run this command for every shard in the 9201 instance (the one you wanna get rid of).

If you have ElasticSearch head, that shard will be purple, and will have "REALLOCATING" status. If you have lots of data, say > 1 GB, it will take awhile for the shard to move - perhaps up to a hour or even more, so be patient. Don't shutdown the instance/node until everything is done moving.

That's it!

Comment: More for my own learning, but couldn't you set replicas to 1 for each index, let them be allocated/popuplated and then turn off the 9201 node? Wouldn't the remaining 'cluster' (of one node on 9200) upgrade the replicas to primaries?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is a possibility but I didn't try.

Comment: @JamesAddison yes that's possible too. Also, there is an offline option just stopping the nodes (or at least disabling flush) and manually merging the two data subfolders, containing the indices for the two different nodes, then starting the node that you want to keep.  Also, in a real server (not your machine) remember to re-enable allocation after you're done moving the shards around.

Comment: @javanna on a related note, what's the best way to backup an Elastic search index?